# Как создать конструктор без параметров в дочернем классе для родительского класса?

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

Создал дочерний класс "AvtobusUp" родительского класса "Avtobus", если не ошибаюсь класс "Avtobus" является подклассом класса "Programm", и в нем у меня лежит внутренняя реализация программы, так вот, я решил попробовать обратиться к методам класса "Programm" с внутренней реализацией классом "Avtobus" с помощью дочернего класса "AvtobusUp", то есть создал объект класса "AvtobusUp", а именно "AvtUp", и с помощью него хотел получить доступ к методам внутренней реализации по примеру переменной "avt" объекта "Avtobus", создать я создал и даже обратиться получилось, но вот програмка в которой я всем этим занимаюсь а именно NeatBeans ругается и просит создать конструктор в дочернем классе "AvtobusUp" для объекта "AvtobusUp", так вот вопрос такой, как создать этот самый конструктор? Я пробовал создать конструктор без параметров а именно AvtobusUp() {}, но выдает ошибку. За ранее прошу прощения, я только начал идти по пути программирования и многое могу путать, возможно мои изъяснения для бывалых программистов звучат крайне не грамотно и доставляют дискомфорт. (Не стал добавлять внутреннюю реализацию кода, так как там довольно много всего, если она понадобиться то я с удовольствием прикреплю и её

```
public class Programm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Avtobus avt = new Avtobus("Calculator");

        avt.setName(666);                  //Номер автобуса
        avt.setNumberOfPassengers(20);     //Количество пассажиров
        avt.setCostOfTravel(30);           //Цена поездки
        avt.setNumberOfStops(10);          //Количество Остановок
        avt.setTheCapacityOfTheBus(40);    //Вместимость автобуса


       avt.Stopped();                  //Остановка
       avt.info1();                    //Первая остановка.Осталось остановок            
       avt.info2();                    //Кол-во пассажиров
       avt.NumberOfAvailableSeats();   //Кол-во свободных мест
       avt.info3();                    //Прибыль с одной остановки
       avt.CalculationOfProfit();      //Подсчет конечной прибыли
AvtobusUp AvtUp = new AvtobusUp();

AvtUp.???

    }

package programm;

import newobject.Avtobus;


public class AvtobusUp extends Avtobus{

    public AvtobusUp(String Calculator) {
        super(Calculator);
    }


}
```

Comment: Покажите, что это за класс Avtobus. А то что то не очень понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите вызвать конструктор `AvtobusUp` без параметров, но в классе `AvtobusUp` его у вас нет.
В Java есть такое правило, **если** в классе **нет ни одного конструктора**, то **компилятор** автоматически **сгенерирует конструктор без параметров**, и если у класса есть родитель, то этот конструктор будет вызывать конструктор родителя без параметров `super()`. Если родителя нет (т.е. родитель - `Object`), то конструктор будет просто пустым.

В вашем случае вы создали конструктор `AvtobusUp(String Calculator)`, соответственно конструктор без параметров компилятор уже не создаст, вам нужно добавить его вручную.

```
public AvtobusUp() {
    super();
}
```

Или, если в родительском классе нет конструктора без параметров, вы можете вызвать конструктор со строкой, передав пустую в аргумент, или же реализовать конструктор без параметров в родителе.

```
public AvtobusUp() {
    super("");
}
```

Про вызов конструктора родителя: если вы явно его не вызываете, то компилятор подставит в первую строку вызов `super()` без параметров, но если у вас не реализован в родителе конструктор без параметров, то вы получите ошибку, в которой будет говорится как раз о том, что вы должны его реализовать. 
Вызов конструктора родителя в дочернем конструкторе обязателен логически, ведь дочерний класс является "достройкой" к родительскому "фундаменту", соответственно сперва нужно инициализировать этот "фундамент".

[документация 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
[документация 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Черт возьми, создаю объект не в родительском классе для которого требуется конструктор без параметров в дочернем классе, а в родительском создать конструктор без параметров забываю, иногда очевидные вещи ускользают и ты теряешься в догадках, спасибо, вы очень помогли мне!